# .NET - Way to display all available vars?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I know absolutely zero about .NET.

Is there a way for me to show all the vars that are available to a user control to use?  If they only showed like in a debug mode or something on the host machine that'd be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it's properties, or the variables that are in its scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are asking about, but if you are using visual studio, [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) will show you all members on a control (and any class, struct or object as well).

The best documentation for .NET is on http://msdn.microsoft.com - this will give you all the information you need to use and access the different objects and controls.

Answer (score 2):

Funny no one mentioned it so far, but you can also use the "properties" panel in VS, to get all events and properties.

That's on design view, when your control is selected.

[image]

(screenshot is from VS 2010, but you have that on just about every VS version).

Answer (score 1):

If you load up your project in visual studio, the intellisense will present you with all the properties and variables you have access to from a given class.

A user control (I'm assuming it's a .ascx file) is exactly that - a .NET class.

It may perhaps be easier to help you find what you want if you specified exactly what it was you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to properties/methods and the like check out the MSDN documentation for the given control.

An example would be the [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) control.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like the autocomplete that shows when pressing cntrl+space?

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/intellisense

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43f44291.aspx